# Salvar preferências de uso - Android

Tags: android, checkbox

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de salvar as preferências de uso de um aplicativo, como por exemplo um checkBox marcado ou a ordenação de uma listView. se puderem passar algum exemplo de código agradeço.

Comment: pode usar o [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) ou a APi [Preference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=pt-br) ai depende do que e como quer fazer. Faz tempo que nao mexo com android entao nao tenho codigo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português! Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como o site funciona. Em relação a sua pergunta me parece que falta mais informações, mostrar o que vc já fez e quais as dificuldades esta a enfrentar, edite ela e acrescente mais informações do problema.

Answer (score 2):

**Cria o objeto SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MinhasPreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Salvando os dados em pares KEY/VALUE**

```
editor.putBoolean("nome_da_chave1", true);      // Salvando valor booleano - true/false
editor.putInt("nome_da_chave2", "int value");   // Salvando valor inteiro integer
editor.putFloat("nome_chave3", "float value");  // Salvando float
editor.putLong("nome_chave4", "long value");    // Salvando long
editor.putString("nome_chave5", "string value");  // Salvando string

// Salva as alterações no objeto SharedPreferences
editor.commit();   // valida as alterações
```

**Lendo os dados de SharedPreferences**

```
boolean estachecado = pref.getBoolean("nome_chave1", true);  // lendo o  boolean
int qualaidade = pref.getInt("nome_chave2", 0);             // lendo o valor inteiro
float total =pref.getFloat("nome_chave3", null);        // lendo o valor  Float
long distancia = pref.getLong("nome_chave4", null);     // lendo o valor Long
String email=pref.getString("nome_chave5", null);       // lendo a String
```

**Excluindo valores da SharedPreferences**

```
editor.remove("nome_chave3"); // excluindo a chave nome_chave3
editor.remove("nome_chave4"); // excluindo a chave nome_chave4

// Salva as alterações em SharedPreferences
editor.commit(); // valida as mudanças
```

**Elimina todos os dados de SharedPreferences**

```
 editor.clear();
 editor.commit(); // Salva as alterações
```

Comment: Perfeito Reginaldo, muito obrigado mesmo!